# Get range of a Graphics object

Tags: graphics, options

Let

```
g1 = Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 4}]}]
```

[image]

It is clear that the `g1` can be contained in a **rectangular region**
whose left-topmost vertice and right-bottomost vertice are `{-3,4}` and `{3,-4}`.

Can we create a function `F1` such that `F1[g1]` becomes `{{-3,4},{3,-4}}`, i.e., a function that yields the range of the graphics object.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[g1, PlotRange]` ?

Comment: @Syed, Thank you!